# How to remove default LXD storage?

Tags: lxc, lxd

I am setting up LXD to play around with conjure-up. I would like to the storage to be mounted only on my RAID device, so it would be good to remove the default storage or replace/redirect it.
I cannot remove the default storage because the default profile uses it.

How can I use the RAID storage with conjure-up and be sure it isn't using my default storage?

Comment: https://github.com/lxc/lxd/blob/master/doc/storage.md This might help?

Comment: Thanks for linking! Can't remember if I saw that earlier or not, but could help others

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The default storage cannot be deleted because it is part of the default profile. The default profile cannot be removed. So the way around this is to push a blank profile to the default profile with;

```
printf 'config: {}\ndevices: {}' | lxc profile edit default
```

Then the default storage will be removed from the default profile, so you will now be able to remove the default storage with;

```
lxc storage delete default
```

Comment: this is the only real working solution

Answer (score 7):

The default storage can be deleted with `sudo lxc storage delete default`.

Comment: When I try this I get `Error: Storage pool "default" has profiles using it: default`

Comment: And `lxc profile delete default` results in `Error: The 'default' profile cannot be deleted`

Comment: Removing the default storage from the default profile lets me delete the storage afterwards. `printf 'config: {}\ndevices: {}' | lxc profile edit default` Ref: https://discuss.linuxcontainers.org/t/error-the-default-profile-cannot-be-deleted/3972/3

Comment: @drganjoo method worked for me: change profile to have empty config and devices, then delete storage.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I seem to have found a workaround that would seem to work.

I delete the default profile

```
lxc profile delete default
```

Then I deleted the lxc-storage

```
sudo rm /var/lib/lxd/storage-pools
```

Finally i linked a directory on my RAID as the deleted directory and create a new storage

```
sudo ln -s /mnt/RAID/lxc-storage-pools /var/lib/lxd/storage-pools
lxc storage create default dir
```

There must be a better way to do this though.

I then reinstalled lxd because I lost my default profile set up...

Comment: That still causes `lxd init` to fail due to `The requested storage pool "default" already exists. Please choose another name.`

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, the above "solution" is in fact absolutely terrible. I have approved your answer, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you are rearranging your storage as I was, you should backup your LXD profiles / LXD network configuration / containers / images **before doing the following**.

- You have to [delete a few things in the following order](https://discuss.linuxcontainers.org/t/how-to-remove-lxd-from-my-system/2336/4)

```
    lxc list
    lxc delete <whatever came from list>
    lxc image list
    lxc image delete <whatever came from list>
    # I did not actually need to delete lxdbr0
    lxc network list
    lxc network delete <whatever came from list>
    echo ‘{“config”: {}}’ | lxc profile edit default
    lxc storage volume list default
    lxc storage volume delete default <whatever came from list>
    lxc storage delete default
```

[image]